# Why is my subview twice the size I want it to be?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview, addsubview

I am adding a `UIView` to a `UIScrollView`.  It will be a horizontal scrollview and I want to add multiple views to it.  The code showing is for one scrollview just to make it simple.  The scroll view is in my storyboard and the view I am adding is a .xib file.  The view gets added, but it is twice the size that I set it to be.  So it is 640 by 244.  The scrollview takes up the bottom 122 pixels of my view.  And the .xib is 320 by 122.  I just have a big button over the top of my .xib so I can tell what is going on when i add it.  The only problem is, is that the .xib that I add to the scrollview is twice as big as I want it to be.  What am I doing wrong??

Let me know if more information is needed.  Thanks!

```
    BADAchievements *temporaryView = (BADAchievements *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BADAchievements" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    CGRect f = temporaryView.frame;
    f.size.width = 320;
    temporaryView.frame = f;

    CGSize s = self.achievementScrollView.contentSize;
    s.width = f.origin.x + f.size.width;
    [self.achievementScrollView setContentSize:s];

    [self.achievementScrollView addSubview:temporaryView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put your code above, i.e. in which method of your view controller?

=> The final frame of your `temporaryView` and/or `achievementScrollView` is not necessarily defined by the dimensions you've specified in the NIB! The frame/bounds may be re-sized later (i.e. when the view loading process is finished and all subviews are layed out).

So you should check if your `autoresizingMask` and `autoresizesSubviews` properties for your subviews are set correctly. (i.e. auto sizing)

Check out the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) on auto resizing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some changes like this :

```
BADAchievements *temporaryView = (BADAchievements *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BADAchievements" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
CGRect f = temporaryView.frame;
CGRect f = CGRectMake(f.origin.x, f.origin.y, 320, f.size.height);
temporaryView.frame = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just messed with it a little bit.  So apparently the code is okay, i just had to take it of auto layout and I changed the autosizing on the UIView so it didn't stretch horizontally or vertically.  Thanks for the response(s).